# What are the standard Web SpeechSynthesis voices?

Tags: html, web, text-to-speech

I would like to implement speech synthesis in different voices, but I want to have a list of the voices supported by all major browsers, similar to the “standard web fonts”.

What is this list in 2018?

Answer (score 0):

Voices list below mentioned-

**For Google Chrome,** ["Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)", "Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)", "Google Deutsch", "Google US English", "Google UK English Female", "Google UK English Male", "Google español", "Google español de Estados Unidos", "Google français", "Google हिन्दी", "Google Bahasa Indonesia", "Google italiano", "Google 日本語", "Google 한국의", "Google Nederlands", "Google polski", "Google português do Brasil", "Google русский", "Google 普通话（中国大陆）", "Google 粤語（香港）", "Google 國語（臺灣）"]

**For Mozilla,** ["Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)", "Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)"]

Comment: I do not see the voices listed where you said. Can you please copypaste and include the results in your answer? I am looking for exactly the voices supported by all major browsers.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/ here you will find the voices list [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/getVoices#Browser_compatibility] and here you will find the browser compatibility

Comment: The first URL returns a 404 and the second URL is same as before - on the mobile phone I don’t see the voices listed in that table!

Comment: Can you please simply include the voices in the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score -1):

The Google voices are still those listed above.  There is no Arabic or Greek, for example.  Although the languages are available and you can write texts in them.  But no voices.
You can learn how to list them in the p5.js free tutorials.  Under text-to-speech.  There, you lean to list voices and languages.